# aquivo .conf do swagger erro:mismatched character expecting Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, swagger

Meu Eclipse me mostra que os arquivos cors.conf e nginx.conf estão com erro. Ao analisar ele aponta os seguintes problemas.
No cors.conf:

```
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS' always;
#
# Custom headers and headers various browsers *should* be OK with but aren't
#
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type' always;
#
# Tell client that this pre-flight info is valid for 20 days
#
add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' $access_control_max_age always; // ERRO --> mismatched character 'a' expecting '{'

if ($request_method = OPTIONS) { // ERRO --> mismatched character 'r' expecting '{' e tbm no viable alternative at input '=' 

  return 204; 
}
```

[image: screenshot eclipse]

A aplicação funciona normalmente mas não sei como tirar esses erros. Acho que deve ser alguma configuração do Eclipse pois isso aconteceu depois de um update e eu não alterei esses arquivos.

Comment: está extensão de arquivo deve está associada alguma linguagem de programação... algo semelhante acontece já aconteceu comigo no sublime... a solução é associar a linguagem correta/desassociar está extensão da linguagem que o eclipse atribuiu a ela.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como sugerido nos comentários, o problema é de configuração do Eclipse. Alterando as associações de arquivos os avisos de erro somem. Dessa maneira *Windows -> Preferences -> General -> Editor -> File assocations*

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]